# Intercept for a specific path with path parameter in JAX-RS

Tags: jax-rs, interceptor

In my REST api I have a resource with multiple sub-resources. Is there any way I can intercept any call to that resource and afterwards continue execution as normal?

For example:

```
/some-resource/{resource-id}
```

is the base path and I have multiple sub-resources like

```
/some-resource/{resource-id}/sub-resource1/...
/some-resource/{resource-id}/sub-resource2/...
...
```

These sub-resources have a complex structure with providers in many different classes.

So is there any way to intercept every call to a resource that starts with the path `/some-resource/{resource-id}`? By intercept I mean calling a method with resource-id as a parameter that is called before any of the sub-recource implementations and may cancel the request by throwing a exception, but otherwise doesn't interfere with normal execution.

Apparently you could use [sub-resource locators](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2496) to have you code called at every request to a base path. It doesn't seem to be designed for interception though as you need to, well, locate the sub-resource, which I do not want to do.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a RequestFilter for that:

```
@Provider
public class SomeResourceFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        if (isSubresourceOfSomeResource(requestContext)) {
            intercept(resourceId(requestContext));
        }
    }

    private boolean isSubresourceOfSomeResource(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        List<PathSegment> pathSegments = requestContext.getUriInfo().getPathSegments();
        return "some-resource".equals(getSegment(requestContext, 0)) && pathSegments.size() > 2;
    }

    private String resourceId(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        return getSegment(requestContext, 1);
    }

    private String getSegment(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, int index) {
        return requestContext.getUriInfo().getPathSegments().get(index).getPath();
    }

    private void intercept(String resourceId) {
        // your code
    }
}
```